# Superset Cache Warmup not working-Docker version

Tags: apache-superset

I have docker version of superset, Version 1.2.0, Ubuntu 18.03,
Have enabled data cache and working as expected.
data cache expire every 2 minutes and setup cache warm up for every three minute, cache warm up is not working, Any suggestion to enable cache warm up?
Where i can find Celery beat or worker log?

My Superset_config.py

```
DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 120,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_results',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://redis:6379/0',
}
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'cache-warmup-hourly': {
        'task': 'cache-warmup',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/3'),
        'kwargs': {
            'strategy_name': 'top_n_dashboards',
            'top_n': 5,
            'since': '7 days ago',
        },
    },
}
```

my Superset docker process status

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                              NAMES
0c4cd8aa4ddc   apache/superset:latest-dev   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   57 minutes ago   Up 42 minutes (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                           superset_worker
df9506be2f84   apache/superset:latest-dev   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes (healthy)     8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp   superset_app
f42c7aee5f3f   node:14                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes                                                  superset_node
5318e34d1607   apache/superset:latest-dev   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   57 minutes ago   Exited (1) 57 minutes ago                                      superset_tests_worker
4874a4f53776   apache/superset:latest-dev   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   57 minutes ago   Exited (0) 55 minutes ago                                      superset_init
fd50a927cfb5   apache/superset:latest-dev   "/usr/bin/docker-ent…"   57 minutes ago   Up 42 minutes (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                           superset_worker_beat
b4b160ecedf5   redis:latest                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes               127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp           superset_cache
a9e5e4f4e938   postgres:10                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes               127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp           superset_db
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks like outstanding defect on superset

https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/9597

https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/15713

Will wait for fix.